# CSS background image in :after element

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to create a CSS button and add an icon to it using :after, but the image never shows up. If I replace the 'background' property with 'background-color:red' then a red box appears so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

HTML:

```
<a class="button green"> Click me </a>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
padding: 15px 50px 15px 15px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.button:after {
content: "";
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: url("http://www.gentleface.com/i/free_toolbar_icons_16x16_black.png") no-repeat -30px -50px no-scroll;
background-color: red;
top: 10px;
right: 5px;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
}

.green {
background-color: #8ce267;
}
```

[You can check this fiddle to see what I mean exactly.](http://jsfiddle.net/KVmJJ/1/)

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

A couple things

(a) you cant have both background-color and background, background will always win. in the example below, i combined them through shorthand, but this will produce the color only as a fallback method when the image does not show.

(b) no-scroll does not work, i don't believe it is a valid property of a background-image. try something like fixed:

```
.button:after {
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background:red url("http://www.gentleface.com/i/free_toolbar_icons_16x16_black.png") no-repeat -30px -50px fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVmJJ/2/) to this and it showed the image.

Comment: Looks like I messed up with the background value there :) Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'd like to add something which isn't that obvious when styling the `:after` element: You will have to set the value of `content` **before** you set the background(image), otherwise, it will not display anything. If you happen to fill `content` with something else than a space and placed it **after** the background(image), then the inserted value *and* the background-image will be shown.

Comment: Just because I'm nit-picky (: You CAN use both background and background color if for whatever reason. The latter will just override the previous e.g. background:1px solid red;background-color:black; === background:1px solid black;

Answer (score 6):

As AlienWebGuy said, you can use background-image. I'd suggest you use background, but it will need three more properties after the URL:

`background: url("http://www.gentleface.com/i/free_toolbar_icons_16x16_black.png") 0 0 no-repeat;`

Explanation: the two zeros are x and y positioning for the image; if you want to adjust where the background image displays, play around with these (you can use both positive and negative values, e.g: 1px or -1px).

No-repeat says you don't want the image to repeat across the entire background. This can also be repeat-x and repeat-y.