# How to download all images from webpage using Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have this script which open a browser page with the desired webpage I want to download all images from this page, how can I do that given this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
class ChromefoxTest:
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url=url
    def chromeTest(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.r=self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
        self.uri=self.r.get_attribute("src")
        self.g=urllib.urlopen(self.uri)
if __name__=='__main__':
    FT=ChromefoxTest("http://www.google.com")
    FT.chromeTest()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib

class ChromefoxTest:
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url=url
        self.uri = []
        self.folder = '/home/palladin/imgs'

    def chromeTest(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.r=self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
        for v in self.r:
            src = v.get_attribute("src")
            self.uri.append(src)
            pos = len(src) - src[::-1].index('/')
            print src[pos:]
            self.g=urllib.urlretrieve(src, "/".join([self.folder, src[pos:]]))

if __name__=='__main__':
    FT=ChromefoxTest("http://www.google.com")
    FT.chromeTest()
```

Comment: it will not download all the images in the page right?

Comment: Script downloads all images with img tag. But backgrounds created with :before and :after pseudoclasses (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695365/css-background-image-in-after-element) will not be downloaded.

Comment: how can I download the pics into a specified folder name?

Comment: ok and if i want to download all other resources like docs, etc how can i do that?

Comment: Same way - by tag name or using other attributes.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'` so `import urllib.request` and then `self.g = urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "/".join([self.folder, src[pos:]]))`